# Redux-saga firebase onAuthStateChanged eventChannel

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, redux-saga

How to handle firebase auth state observer in redux saga?

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

});
```

I want to run `APP_START` saga when my app starts which will run `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` observer and will run other sagas depending on the callback.

As I understand **eventChannel** is right way to do it. But I don't understand how to make it work with `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`.

Can someone show how to put `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` in to eventChannel?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [eventChannel](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/Channels.md#using-the-eventchannel-factory-to-connect-to-external-events). Here is an example code:

```js
function getAuthChannel() {
  if (!this.authChannel) {
    this.authChannel = eventChannel(emit => {
      const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => emit({ user }));
      return unsubscribe;
    });
  }
  return this.authChannel;
}

function* watchForFirebaseAuth() {
  ...
  // This is where you wait for a callback from firebase
  const channel = yield call(getAuthChannel);
  const result = yield take(channel);
  // result is what you pass to the emit function. In this case, it's an object like { user: { name: 'xyz' } }
  ...
}
```

When you are done, you can close the channel using `this.authChannel.close()`.

Comment: i am using 'ReduxSagaFirebase' so i don't have firebase object , how i can check for the 'onAuthStateChange' ?

Comment: @AliYarKhan I would start here https://redux-saga-firebase.js.org/reference/dev/auth/#channel

Comment: watchForFirebaseAuth will not watch. Its a one off call. no different to removing the getAuthChannel function and dealing with onAuthStateChanged directly

Comment: according to eventChannel documentation you provided the code in watchForFirebaseAuth should be wrapped by a while(true) loop.

Answer (score 5):

Create your own function `onAuthStateChanged()` that will return a `Promise`

```
function onAuthStateChanged() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        resolve(user);
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Ops!'));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Then use [call](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/) method to get the `user` synchronously

```
const user = yield call(onAuthStateChanged);
```

Comment: onAuthStateChanged is not defined. If I change to "onAuthStateChanged" then listener is not a function.

Comment: first of all, this is not a valid "observable" , it negates the whole idea of "watching" for auth state changes, second issue is that the `else` clause is not actually an error, because if `user` is null, this means that user has signed out, please refer to https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/a6ecc6cc9b1beb73583a5180292e9680630005d9/auth/index.js#L43-L53

Answer (score 1):

This could be handled in the Saga such as the following for **Redux Saga Firebase:**

```
// Redux Saga: Firebase Auth Channel
export function* firebaseAuthChannelSaga() {
  try {
    // Auth Channel (Events Emit On Login And Logout)
    const authChannel = yield call(reduxSagaFirebase.auth.channel);

    while (true) {
      const { user } = yield take(authChannel);

      // Check If User Exists
      if (user) {
        // Redux: Login Success
        yield put(loginSuccess(user));
      }
      else {
        // Redux: Logout Success
        yield put(logoutSuccess());
      }
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

here is how you would run the `onAuthStateChanged` observable using `redux-saga` features (mainly `eventChannel`)

```
import { eventChannel } from "redux-saga";
import { take, call } from "redux-saga/effects";

const authStateChannel = function () {
  return eventChannel((emit) => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
      (doc) => emit({ doc }),
      (error) => emit({ error })
    );

    return unsubscribe;
  });
};

export const onAuthStateChanged = function* () {
  const channel = yield call(authStateChannel);

  while (true) {
    const { doc, error } = yield take(channel);
    if (error) {
      // handle error
    } else {
      if (doc) {
        // user has signed in, use `doc.toJSON()` to check
      } else {
        // user has signed out
      }
    }
  }
};
```

please note that other solutions that don't utilize channel sagas are not optimal for `redux-saga`, because turning an observable into a promise is not a valid solution in this case since you would need to call the promise each time you anticipate a change in authentication state (like for example: taking every `USER_SIGNED_IN` action and calling the "promisified" observable), which will negate the whole purpose of an observable